# angular [...XXX] これはなにを意味するのでしょうか

Tags: javascript, angular4

angular version 4.4.4 になりますが、

```js
this.tableInfo.dataList = [...this.tableInfo.dataList]
```

このようなロジックを見つけまして、`this.tableInfo.dataList`はclassの配列になります。
同要素に対して `[...XXX]`を囲み代入しているのですが、何を意味しているのか分かりません。

もしご存知な方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示お願いいたします。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript 2015の[スプレッド構文](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)で、質問の使い方では、配列をコピーする動作です。

Comment: 理解しました。ありがとうございます。